# Importing IntelliJ IDEA classic keymap into VS Code in MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, keymaps

I have customized some shortcuts in the **IntelliJ IDEA classic** keymap. I want to import all those shortcuts into VS-Code as sometimes I have to use both IDEs.

I have installed a plugin in VS-Code to easily provide a keymap JSON file. But I can't find my current IntelliJ keymap file JSON file.

I do not find a folder called `keymaps` as mentioned here -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#custom_keymap_location

I already imported [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps) keymap into VS-Code. But as I stated I have some customizations I have done on top of the default **IntelliJ IDEA classic** keymap. So, I'm clearly missing those shortcuts.

```
OS: Darwin x64 21.1.0
VS-Code : 1.65.0
IntelliJ Ultimate Version: 2021.2.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking from `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/settingsRepository/repository/keymaps/` instead of `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/keymaps/`

There you might find the XML settings of your custom keymaps.

If the folder is not there, does that mean Jetbrains might have overridden your custom keymaps? Could you check?

Jetbrains only put a custom keymap file as additional settings on top of the default keymap. ie. If I copy a macOS default keymap and edit some, there would be an entry in the keymap.xml

```
<keymap name="..." parent="macOS" >
...
</keymap>
```